# Viewport bounds online update. OpenLayers

Tags: extents, update, openlayers-2

I am trying to extract the bound box coordinates of viewport (the box that is displayed). I want to know the coordinates all the time and updated when zoom in/out or dragged. I cheched that 'getExtent' function returns the Bound coordinates, but I am not able to update the values. The code used is the one below (the script).

```
<script>
    var map;
    function Initialize() {
        LoadMap(40.36, -3.66, 6);
    }
    //***************************************
    function LoadMap(lat, lon, zoom) {
        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);

        var options = {
        projection: "EPSG:900913",
        center: lonLat,
        units: 'km'
        };

        map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapDiv", options);
        var osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(null, null, zoom);

        map.addLayers([osmLayer]);
        map.addControls([
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
        ]);

        //Zoom the map
        map.zoomTo(zoom);

        $("#Bounds1").text("    ->     "+map.size);
        $("#Bounds2").text("    ->     "+map.getExtent());
        $("#Bounds3").text("    ->     "+map.getExtent().transform(toProjection,fromProjection));
        $("#Bounds4").text("    ->     "+map.calculateBounds());
    }
</script>
```

In this example, the map loads on Madrid and displays the coordinates of bound correctly although it seems to be wrong because  the 'zoomTo' function rapidly changes the view to afar view of all Spain.

So, how can the values on #Bounds labels can be updated? If it is not possible to do it in real-time, they can be updated each second or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register the zoomend- and moveend-Event for your map like this:

```
 function bounds_update() {
     $("#Bounds1").text("    ->     " + map.size);
     $("#Bounds2").text("    ->     " + map.getExtent());
     $("#Bounds3").text("    ->     " + map.getExtent().transform(toProjection, fromProjection));
     $("#Bounds4").text("    ->     " + map.calculateBounds());
 }

 map.events.on({
     'zoomend': function (e) {
         bounds_update()
     },
         'moveend': function (e) {
         bounds_update()
     }
 });
```

PS: You just have to have a look at the scope of your variables *fromProjection* and *toProjection* to make sure you can "reach" them from within a function like the one I called "bounds_update". A quick and dirty solution would be to use global variables even if this is not best practice.

live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/5by0u9gk/

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I found your answer very interesting and with the infomartion on the link http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.events I have added some maybe useful extra code for others.

Comment: @isal I think you should add your extra code as another answer that references http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/144613  It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I edit Thomas' answer. I will wait to check if he accepts the extra code to have a more general answer. If not, I will add it as a new answer.

Comment: @isal thanks for your edit proposal but i also think it's better just to add it as a new answer. Perhaps it's also worth mentioning that it's not following the DRY principle (as well as the global variables are considered as bad style) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thomas' answer works perfectly but I checked that it is not necesary to create a new function and define *fromProjection* and *toProjection* as global variables introducing directly the following code inside the script just at the end.

```
map.events.register("moveend", map, function(){
    $("#Bounds2").text("    ->     "+map.getExtent());
    $("#Bounds3").text("    ->     "+map.getExtent().transform(toProjection,fromProjection));
});
map.events.register("zoomend", map, function(){
    $("#Bounds2").text("    ->     "+map.getExtent());
    $("#Bounds3").text("    ->     "+map.getExtent().transform(toProjection,fromProjection));
});
```